# Rational Software Architect (ver 6 & 7.5). There are no projects that can be added or removed from the server

Tags: websphere, rational-rsa

we are facing a weird problem with Rational Software Architect. 
We have a web application A which is working fine in RSA 6. Now I upgraded my RSA to 7.5 and the same project was throwing "There are no projects that can be added or removed from the server" when I trying to add them through "Add/Remove projects" button.

So we thought, this might be a bug in RSA 7.5.

Now, we have another web project B, which is running fine in RSA 7.5 is throwing the same "no projects to add or remove" error in RSA 6.0. We tried to run on both WAS 6.0.2 and WAS 7 but both are giving the same error in RSA 6.

So there should be definitely some configuration issues in the project than problem with the RSA.

Please help.

Thanks,
Santu

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by letting the RSA migration wizard to continue. Previously when it asked about the Migration, I used to decline it since it will modify the web.xml, ibm-web-bnd.xmi and ibm-web-ext.xmi files.